# Windows 10 High RAM/Memory usage (practically 100% full time)

Tags: windows, memory, ramdisk

So, im using a laptop (Legion y520 i5-7300HQ 2.5Ghz), i have 8Gb RAM (factory) and a 1TB HDD (factory) with a 250Gb nvme SSD (installed). The problem has been happening for a month now, my memory usage is always at 97-99% (it got to 100 once and i got blue screened). These are the processes running in my pc. As you can see they really dont add up to even a few GB.
[tasks running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rgBE2.png)

For example: i updated windows and as i turned the pc on it's memory usage was like this after an hour(started at 44%).
[60%usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DfrAy.png)

after 3 more hours (pc had been shut off for some time) it was like this:
[70%usage](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FnoR8.png)

Of course, the day after already showed high 90's%
It seems that, for any reason, the ram memory isn't removing all the data that WAS used, and it acumulates over time

What i've tried:

- running DISM check through cmd, doesen't report anything
- uptading all drivers
- checking for viruses (found 1 in memory through malwarebytes, solved the problem for like a day or so, even with the virus still in quarentine)
- updating windows (it also solves the problem for a day more or less, RAM goes up again to full after some hours)
- already have windows update and search disabled, sysmain as well

so here i am, hoping that i can solve this so that i dont have to check the hardware itself.
Any ideas of what it could be? or how to solve it? thanks

---

virual memory-> [virtual memory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w0fjL.png)
rammap -> [rammap](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JirUD.png)

Comment: What is your virtual memory set to?  Please provide an (English) screenshot.

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot of RAMMap from Sysinternals/Microsoft?

Comment: @Ramhound , the you go, on the question

Comment: @HelpingHand done

Comment: Doesn't look too bad, Paged and Non-Paged Pool seem "ok".  Did you watch the video referenced from the RAMMap page - https://channel9.msdn.com/shows/defrag-tools/defrag-tools-6-rammap That is work a listen.

Comment: You can use mdsched and memtest86 to check for any RAM problems.

Comment: @XeнεiΞэnвϵς yes, i have used windows memory diagnostics and it found no issues whatsoever

Comment: @HelpingHand i'll be checking that

Answer (score 0):

Process might be hidden from task manager. Try to install alternative that shows more.
[Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) should work.

Answer (score 0):

The [recommended minimum RAM](https://winaero.com/the-real-system-requirements-for-windows-10/) for 64 bit Windows 10 is 16 GB.
Using 90-100% of your 8 GB seems like a reasonable outcome.

The solution would be replace the current ram with larger modules.
Tutorials for how to open the laptop up and replace the ram are common on [youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zei9xnaEWGA).

If it were my laptop I'd buy 2x 16 GB DDR4 SODIMM sticks (32 GB total) at around US$70 each from a reputable online shop.

Comment: i've had this laptop for 2 and something years now. This is the first time that this happened. Windows only uses about 2GB, lets say almost 3 if you want to, without any major software running and olnly minor (Mb) tasks, having more than 50% ram usage its absurd. (this is how i see it)